# How could I use Phalcon\Tag with an external template engine such as Smarty in phalcon 0.5

Tags: smarty, smarty3, phalcon

I followed [this docs](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/views.html#template-engines) and created an adapter for Smarty. And I want to use Smarty as the default template engine in my project. In this case, can I use Phalcon\Tag or $this->partial() inside the .tpl file? And how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller you can do something like this:

```
$register_link = \Phalcon\Tag::linkTo('register', 'Register');
$index_link    = \Phalcon\Tag::linkTo('index', 'Index');

$this->view->setVar('my_register_link', $register_link);
$this->view->setVar('my_index_link', $index_link);
```

In the view you can do this:

```
<div id='links'>
{if $somevariable}
    {$my_register_link}
{/if}
{$my_index_link}
</div>
```

Comment: I tried with smarty3. The first way doesn't work out while the second does but a little complicated.I want to use smarty because it's UI designer-friend syntax. It will be very useful if the native engine use a php-independent syntax I think.

Comment: Can you please edit my response so that we can keep the option that works?